# Can I take an immediate action after I've used a swift before my next go

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The  scenario is

Round # 1
  Initiative #10. A monk spends a swift action to use a ki point

Round # 2
  Initiative #20. The monk is attacked and uses an immediate action to do something cool.

Now if the monk was attacked in initiative number 5 of round 1, I think it's clear that he couldn't use an immediate action (one swift action per round, and he's used it). In Round #2 Initiative #20, it's not his go yet, so has his 'access to the immediate action' refreshed?

I'm after a RAW answer if that's possible

Comment: I'd like to point out that the example in the question is wrong.  The monk can use an immediate action at any point after his turn in round 1, because an immediate action takes your NEXT turn's swift to use.  Since it is after his turn, his immediate action will use round 2's swift action regardless of if you are still in round 1 (after his move) or now in round 2 (before his move).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes**

[Here's the rule](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Immediate-Actions) (emphasis mine):

> Much like a swift action, an immediate action consumes a very small
>   amount of time but represents a larger expenditure of effort and
>   energy than a free action. However, unlike a swift action, an
>   immediate action can be performed at any time—even if it's not your
>   turn. Casting feather fall is an immediate action, since the spell can
>   be cast at any time.
>
> Using an immediate action on your turn is the same as using a swift
>   action and counts as your swift action for that turn. **You cannot use
>   another immediate action or a swift action until after your next turn
>   if you have used an immediate action when it is not currently your
>   turn (effectively, using an immediate action before your turn is
>   equivalent to using your swift action for the coming turn)**. You also
>   cannot use an immediate action if you are flat-footed.

The way this works is that if you use an immediate action and it's not your turn, that counts as your swift action for your *upcoming* turn.

If you're not flat-footed, you can use one immediate action. If you do, you don't get a swift action when your turn comes around again. If you use a swift actin on your turn, you can still use an immediate once it's not your turn (and it counts as your swift for your next turn). Immediate actions are restored at the end of your turn, the end of the round isn't relevant.

The Monk could also use it on Round #1, Initiative #5. If he did, he couldn't use a swift in round 2 when its his turn, and he couldn't use an immediate in round 2 until after his turn (so he couldn't use it on Round #2, Initiative 20).

Here's an example of the flow:

1. Combat Starts. Presuming the monk is flat footed, he can't use an immediate until his turn.
2. Round 1, initiative 10 - Monk's turn. Monk uses a swift. At the end of his turn, his immediate action becomes available.
3. Round 1, initiative 5 - Monk uses an immediate.
4. Round 2, initiative 20 - Monk would like to use another immediate, but can't because his turn hasn't happened yet.
5. Round 2, initiative 10 - Monk's turn. He cannot use a swift because he used an immediate. At the end of this turn, he gets his immediate back.
6. Round 2, initiative 5 - Monk can use an immediate, but doesn't.
7. Round 3, initiative 20 - Monk can still use an immediate, but doesn't.
8. Round 3, initiative 10 - Monk's turn, he can use a swift.

Comment: Thanks. That's clear. I now need to see if I ACTUALLY understand it!